# MS Flow - Approval Email - Markdown Table

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, flow, power-automate, approval

I am new to MS Flow, I am creating an approval process where I have to send data in a table.

I have an array, which is

```
[
  {
    "Header": [
      "Username",
      "Hname",
      "RE"
    ],
    "Data": [
      "aa",
      "bb",
      "cc"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Header": [
      "Username",
      "Hname",
      "RE"
    ],
    "Data": [
      "aa11",
      "bb11",
      "cc33"
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I create a Markdown table from the above array to get the below table?

```
|Header  |Data |

|Username|aa   |
|Hname   |bb   |
|RE      |cc   |
|Username|aa1  |
|Hname   |bb2  |
|RE      |cc3  |
```

[image: Error]

I have passed the above array from the select output ie. body('select') to foreach action, and foreach output ie. items(apply_to_each) to parse_JSON.
Below is the output from Parse_JSON.

```
{
  "Header": [
    "Username",
    "Hostname",
    "RE"
  ],
  "Data": [
    "aa",
    "bb",
    "cc"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The array given has an extra comma (,) in sub-arrays. You can use Parse JSON as @Ganesh suggested and create HTML table. However, you can also **manually** create  HTML Table by using [Apply to each] action and  **string functions** in Expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this a complex array, I used a combination of [Parse JSON] and [Apply to each] actions, and string functions to generate the HTML table to get the output as requested.

See the screenshots and explanation below.

[image]

**varArray** - a string variable, contains the array string that has been provided.

**varHTMLTable** - a string variable, initialized with a Table layout with some styles. See Expression 1.

**Expression 1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
th, td {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  width:200px;
}
th {text-align:left; }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Data</th> 
    <th></th>
  </tr>
<!--add a blank row between [Header] and [Data] Rows -->
  <tr>
    <td style="border:0px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border:0px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border:0px;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
```

**Detail 1**

[image]

**Expression 2**

```
concat('<tr><td>', items('Apply_to_each')['Header']?[0], '</td><td>', items('Apply_to_each')['Data']?[0], '</td><td> </td></tr>',

'<tr><td>', items('Apply_to_each')['Header']?[1], '</td><td>', items('Apply_to_each')['Data']?[1], '</td><td> </td></tr>',

'<tr><td>', items('Apply_to_each')['Header']?[2], '</td><td>', items('Apply_to_each')['Data']?[2], '</td><td> </td></tr>'

)
```

**Detail 2**

[image]

**The Final output seen in the email body**

Note: Table styles can be adjusted as needed.

[image]

---

### Updated for a Markdown Table

The process is the same to generate a Markdown Table.
However, for adding a line break, only `</br>` worked for me.

Initialize a string variable, **varMarkdownTable**, with the table header

```
concat('## Markdown Table </br>', '|  Header | Data |</br>', '| :---------: | :---------: |</br>', '|  |  |</br>')
```

Within **Apply to each**, using [Append to string variable], append the table body string to **varMarkdownTable** variable

```
concat('| ', items('Apply_to_each')['Header']?[0], ' | ', items('Apply_to_each')['Data']?[0], ' |</br>', '| ', items('Apply_to_each')['Header']?[1], ' | ', items('Apply_to_each')['Data']?[1], ' |</br>', '| ', items('Apply_to_each')['Header']?[2], ' | ', items('Apply_to_each')['Data']?[2], '|</br>')
```

Generated Markdown Table as seen in outlook email

[image]

Copy the the output and verify using **Visual Studio Code** or [MarkdownLivePreview](https://markdownlivepreview.com/)

[image]

Comment: Hi @Matiur Rahman, I want to create a Markdown table in 'Start and wait for an approval' Action, not HTML table.

Comment: Updated my original post showing how to build Markdown string in Power Automate. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Parse JSON** and then **Select** action to selecting specific properties you want to add to table.

Then you need to use **Create HTML Table** action in Power Automate to generate table from JSON data.

Check below references for detailed information:

1. [Create And Format HTML Table Using Microsoft Flow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-and-format-html-table-using-microsoft-flow-and-sharepoint-online/)
2. [Handling JSON in Microsoft Flow](https://spmaestro.com/handling-json-in-microsoft-flow/)
3. [How to use Select to simplify Create-HTML-Table](https://www.google.com/amp/johnliu.net/blog/2018/4/how-to-use-select-to-simplify-create-html-table-and-create-csv-in-microsoftflow%3fformat=amp)

Comment: Hi @ganesh, I have created the above array from the select action. Basically, the header contains the key and the data contains the value. I have to create a markdown table for the approval email. I have edited the question please have a look.